# Count rows in a table based on each row value

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm struggling with following problem. I want to create a query in spark that runs a query for every row on existing table based on current column value.

Table can be simplified like this:

| job_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2000 | 2-1-2000 |
| 2 | 1-1-2000 | 3-1-2000 |
| 3 | 2-1-2000 | 4-1-2000 |
| 4 | 5-1-2000 | 7-1-2000 |

I want to create query which adds another column that counts how many jobs have already been started at each rows start date.

Output for this table should look as following

| job_id | start_date | end_date | jobs_active_at_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2000 | 2-1-2000 | 2 (active jobs id - 1,2) |
| 2 | 1-1-2000 | 3-1-2000 | 2 (active jobs id - 1,2) |
| 3 | 2-1-2000 | 4-1-2000 | 3 (active jobs id - 1,2,3) |
| 4 | 5-1-2000 | 7-1-2000 | 1 (only job 4 is active) |

I've tried to do subquery

```
%sql
SELECT
    t1.id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.start_date <= t1.start_date AND t2.end_date >= t1.start_date) 
FROM table t1
```

But databricks returned an error

> AnalysisException: Correlated column is not allowed in predicate

I guess this method doesn't have best efficiency either.

What is best approach to tackle such problem?

Comment: Why would you expect 0 for job_id 4?

Comment: You are right It should include itself, i've made a typo

Answer (score 2):

You can just join the table to itself on the dates.

```
select
t1.job_id,
t1.start_date,
t1.end_date,
count (t2.job_id)
from
Table1 t1
inner join Table1 t2
    on t2.start_date <= t1.start_date AND t2.end_date >= t1.start_date
group by
t1.job_id,
t1.start_date,
t1.end_date;
```